# The diameter of the symmetric group generated by the transposition $(1,2)$ and both left and right rotations by $(1,2,\ldots,n)$

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, permutations, symmetric-groups, oeis

I am trying to understand the following sequence:

[A186783](https://oeis.org/A186783) -The [diameter of the symmetric group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diameter_of_a_group) generated by the transposition $(1,2)$ and both left and right rotations by $(1,2,\ldots,n)$. The sequence is $0,1,2,6,10,15,21,28,35,45,55,66,\ldots$ If we swap out the $2$ with a $3$ we would have the "triangular numbers", ${n+1 \choose 2}$. With that exception what would make us believe this sequence is not the "triangular numbers".

Comment: I think the following comment in the linked OEIS page answers your question : Conjecture: $a(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} Stirling_1(n+k-1, (n-1)*k)$ This formula holds for all known n. - Arkadiusz Wesolowski, Mar 30 2013.

Comment: Sometimes it happens that a sequence with an origin in extremal combinatorics almost coincides with a simple sequence. I also encountered this phenomenon about twenty years ago, see sequence [A090701](https://oeis.org/A090701). I guess it can happen because a generic example almost follows some pattern, which is locally distorted, for small values.

Comment: For instance, a similar effect we have given a shape which tiles the plane are looking for a maximum number of shapes which can fit in a square of size $n$. Asymptotically it is $n^2$ divided by the area of the shape, but it usually is a bit smaller due to the boundaries of the square forbid to fill it tightly.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy: That is a slightly crazy formula -- only the first term of the sum is ever nonzero, except for the exceptional case, where a correction of 1 is applied by the second term.  And this first term would be much more simply expressed as the triangular number it is, instead of using Stirling numbers of the first kind (which also gives a sign error). Maybe Wesolowski proposed the formula as a joke!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your conjecture matches the one in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences**

Wesolowski's comment in the [OEIS page](https://oeis.org/A186783) conjectures a formula involving Stirling numbers of the first kind.  The formula is expressed as a negated sum, but in fact only the first term of this sum is non-zero, except for the exceptional case $n=3$ when the second term makes an adjustment by one.  And the first term, S(n,n-1), is exactly a (negative) triangular number.  So Wesolowski's conjecture and yours are the same.

**Small cases**

The cases up to $n=3$ can be considered to be special cases.  For $n=1$ the swap generator is ill-defined.  For $n=2$, the three generators are all the same.  For $n=3$, there are two maximally distant permutations, (1 3 2) and (3 2 1), at distance 2 instead of 3.

**The general case**

But for $n \ge 4$, the pattern falls into place.  There is always (verified up to $n=12$) a unique maximally distant permutation, and it is of the form (2$\;$1 $\,n$ $\;(n-1)\;$ $\ldots\,$ 5 4 3).  In other words, it is the reversed sequence, rotated right twice.  If you imagine a device that lets you rotate beads, and swap two at a certain location, then the maximally distant configuration is just the mirror image of the device's current configuration, with the mirror centered at the center of the swapping location.

```
       * --- *       Imagine colored beads at the stars, which can be
      /       \      rotated around the ring either way.  At any time,
     /         \     the two at the top can be swapped with each other.
    *           *    
     \         /     Then the configuration needing the most moves to
      \       /      get to is the mirror image (the left-right flip)
       * --- *       of the current configuration.

  This figure shows n=6, but the claim appears to be true for any n≥4.

  The number of required moves is the triangular number C(n,2).
```

It seems you can get to the flipped configuration optimally by flipping each half of the puzzle separately, using a two-way bubble sort.

However, it remains an open problem both to show that the mirror image is the hardest configuration to reach for all $n \ge 4$, and to show that the mirror image cannot be reached in fewer than $\binom{n}{2}$ moves.